# assigning "exports" to a function in nodejs module doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express

in one file (otherFile.js) I have this:

```
exports = function() {}
```

in my main file I have this:

```
var thing = require('./otherFile.js');
new thing();
```

however this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

and if in otherFile.js I have this instead:

```
exports.myFunction = function() {}
```

and in my main file I have this:

```
var thing = require('./otherFile.js');
new thing.myFunction();
```

then it works perfectly. Why is it that I'm not allowed to assign a function to the exports variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the exported object itself you will have assign it to `module.exports`. This should work (in otherFile.js):

```
module.exports = function() {}
```

To elaborate a little more why:

Reassigning a variable does not change the object it referenced before (which is basically what you are doing). A simple example would be this:

```
function test(a) {
    a = { test: 'xyz' };
    console.log(a);
}

var x = { test: 'abc' };
test(x);

console.log(x);
```

Basically by assigning exports to the function you'd expect the variable `x` to have a value of `{ test: 'xyz' }` but it will still be `{ test: 'abc' }` because the function introduces a new variable (which is still referencing the same object however so changing `a.test` will change the output of both). That's basically how CommonJS modules (which is what Node uses) work, too.

Comment: interesting! Why is this so?

Comment: Because the `exports` variable is just a reference to the object. Reassigning the variable won't change that object. Changing the property of the parent object (`module`) will however.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
!function(exports) {
    // your module code
    exports = 12345
}(module.exports)

console.log(module.exports)
```

It won't work, and it's easy to see why. Node.js `exports` object is defined exactly like this, with an exception of arguments ordering.

---

So always use `module.exports` instead of `exports`, it'll do the right thing.